# TypeScript Error TS7016 with path mappings

Tags: typescript

I'm having a problem with path mapping in TypeScript 4.1.3.

The following files work fine before any compilation (no .js files present). After compilation, with .js files present, TypeScript emits the following error on '@framework/hello.js':

```
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@framework/hello.js'
```

If I remove the path mapping, everything works fine:

```
import Hello from './framework/hello.js';
```

If I remove the .js extension:

```
import Hello from '@framework/hello';
```

then TypeScript is happy but I get a Node error at runtime

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '.../framework/hello'
```

because of the missing extension in the compiled JavaScript file.

I've tried

```
"allowJs": true
```

but it didn't seem to make any difference.

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions":
    {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitAny": true,

        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths":
        {
            "@framework/*": ["./framework/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

index.ts

```
import Hello from '@framework/hello.js';

const hello: Hello = new Hello();

hello.say("Hello");
```

framework/hello.ts

```
export default class Hello
{
    public say(str: string)
    {
        console.log(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove .js extension in import ?

Comment: Yes. I've updated my question.